# How do I pass values to Airflow variables?

Tags: python, airflow

I am working on a pipeline code where I'm passing string values to a JSON payload variable (python).
Example:

```
payload_reportType = {
        "advertiserId": advertiser_id,
        "startDate": start_date,
        "endDate": end_date,
        "reportType": "reportType",
        "reportMetrics": [
        ....
        ....
        ],
}
```

There are multiple (python) variables for different report types which we use to send POST requests to API endpoint.
These payloads take up too much of the lines of the code and to reduce this, I thought of using Airflow variables where I can simply store the payload values and call them in my python code.

The values of `advertiser_id`, `start_date`,`end_date` are already declared in the method which calls the API. I have to simply assign them as values to this JSON string.

I tried Jinja notations which should automatically passing the respective values in the (Airflow) variable.

Example:

```json
{
        "advertiserId": "{{ var.advertiser_id }}",
        "startDate": "{{ var.start_date }}",
        "endDate": "{{ var.end_date }}",
        "reportType": "reportType",
        "reportMetrics": [
        ....
        ....
}
```

And I passed this in a test code:

```
advertiserId = '24883'
startDate = '2023-02-01'
endDate = '2023-02-10'
payload_variable_string = Variable.get("payload_keyword")
logging.info(payload_variable_string)
```

It still does not work and after checking the value using print, the jinja notation itself is visible and not the values.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer related to airflow Variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77949387/how-can-i-dynamically-change-a-bucket-name-in-an-airflow-dag#77949461