Pass Airflow Variables to Task
Is there an accepted best practice for passing or accessing encrypted Airflow variables/connections in modules executed during the DagRun? Is passing it as an argument to the PythonOperator with op_kwargs sufficient?
Thanks in advance.

Variables have global scope. No need to pass them, just use get and update API. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77949387/how-can-i-dynamically-change-a-bucket-name-in-an-airflow-dag/77949461#77949461 Connections are also global scope. If you want to pass arguments around use xcoms instead.

Variables have global scope. No need to pass them, just use get and update API.
Pls see below answer for more info.
stackoverflow.com/questions/77949387/…
Connections are also global scope. If you want to pass arguments around use xcoms instead.
